# change the Vertical constraints in Iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints, autolayout

I have 2 views(X & Y) in my nib file. I am using Auto-Layout for this.

My second view(Y) is bottom space is 0 to view means it is at bottom of the main View.
My first view (x) is bottom space is 0 to View(Y) means X & Y conncted each other.

If I remove the view (Y) from the coding then View (X) should be place as view (y) means View (X) should be down to mani view bottom.

My try is as follow:

```
    [vwOperation2 removeFromSuperview];
    NSLog(@"%@",vwOperation2.constraints);
     vwOperation2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [vwOperation2 updateConstraints];
      vwOperation1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [vwOperation1 updateConstraints];

    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
```

**Help me to solve this..**

**Thanks in advance...**

Comment: Are you removing the now invalid constraints / adding a new constraint to X to pin to the superview?

Answer (score 2):

Never call `updateConstraints` directly. 
Use rather `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` and `needsUpdateConstraints`.

Regarding the problem.

In `UIView`'s `updateConstraints` method add constraints you need considering state of the view. For example:

```
- (void)updateConstraints {
    // You can remove all the constraints here are only some of them
    // You may have some IBOutlets for constraints
    [self removeConstraints:self.constraints];

    if (self.shouldHideX) {        
        // add proper constrains here
        // or modify constants
    } else {
        // add proper constrains here
        // or modify constants
    }
    [super updateConstraints];
}
```

Then in you code triggering changes you should do something like:

```
- (void)doSomethingAwesome {
    self.shouldHideX = // determine that

    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [self.view setNeedsLayout];

    // if you want to animate that
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                     animations:^{
                   [self needsUpdateConstraints];
                   [self layoutIfNeeded];
     }              completion:^(BOOL finished){ 
       // here e.g. remove your subview from superview
 }];    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably my answer will be old-fashioned/not optimal, but it works.

- set two IBOutlets for constraints (let's say constraintForViewY and constraintForViewX)
- init them with

> constraintForViewY.constant = 0

and

> constraintForViewX.constant = YView.frame.size.height;

when you delete YView:

> constraintForViewX.constant = 0;

(probably with animation)